# Properties of pmatch function

Tags: r, string-matching, na, partial, no-match

I don't understand the behavior of the built-in function *pmatch* (partial string matching).

The description provides the following example:

```
pmatch("m",   c("mean", "median", "mode")) # returns NA instead of 1,2,3
```

but using:

```
pmatch("m", "mean") # returns 1, as I would have expected.
```

Could anybody explain to me this behavior?

Comment: `nomatch`: the value to be returned at non-matching or multiply partially matching positions. Note that it is coerced to integer.

Comment: Did you only want an explanation of why `pmatch` is broken (returns NA) for multiple partial matches, or an actual solution? I posted the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation:

`nomatch`: the value to be returned at non-matching or multiply partially matching positions. Note that it is coerced to integer.

The `nomatch` defaults to NA (i.e., if there are multiple partial matches then NA will be returned).

```
pmatch("me",   c("mean", "median", "mode")) 
[1] NA  # returns NA instead of 1,2 since multiple partial matches

pmatch("mo",   c("mean", "median", "mode")) 
[1] 3   # since single partial match
```

Comment: Why does this give NA? `pmatch("ed",   c("mean", "median", "mode"))`

Comment: Thank you. So per default, x can only be used once. If I wanted to allow multiple partial matches, I would have to call pmatch for each individual string, I guess.

Comment: @zx8754 seems the match must start from the first character of the second argument

Comment: @Krisselack or you can use grep / regular expressions

Answer (score 4):

**Use `grep` instead - the NA-on-duplicates behavior of `pmatch` is incredibly annoying**:

```
grep("^m",   c("mean", "median", "mode"))
[1] 1 2 3

> grep("ed",   c("mean", "median", "mode"))
[1] 2
```

The only downside is that `pmatch(x, table...` is vectorized for both args, but `grep` only for the second arg. So `grep` can't take a vector of patterns. But you can use `stringi`, or else `sapply`.

Comment: "incredibly annoying" to me too, mostly because, I don't know how to use it.

Comment: @zx8754: it's not that you don't understand. `pmatch` is literally broken-by-design. Its default behavior is stupid, and there's no switch to turn that off. Since its input is vectorized, of course you would expect it to handle partial-matches, but it doesn't. `grep` does everything you need and more - partial matches, capture groups, backreferences etc. I have never needed `pmatch` and never seen it used.